# Выполнить Ajax запрос и перейти на страницу

Tags: ajax, php

Посылаю Ajax GET запрос таким кодом:

```
//...Тут объявлены переменные
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "//url.com/m.php",
            data: "bm="+bm1+"&me="+me1,
    });
```

Нужно перейти на эту страницу (url.com/m.php) с заданными параметрами в data. Догадываюсь, что нужно писать  success: function() {}, но что именно туда писать?

Comment: query string можно сформировать с помощью [$.param(data);](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

Comment: success: function(){  
  window.location.href = 'http://your.site/page.php?bm=' + bm1 + '&me=' + me1;
}  

  
Если я правильно понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если нужно отправить ajax, в случае успешного ответа перейти на другую страницу, то в success надо написать document.location.href = 'http://your.site/page.html';. Url на который переходить можно возвращать в ответе ajax.

Comment: В том то и дело, что url должен быть с параметрами, а не чистый

Comment: ну, в чем проблема? Сформируйте url в php, в ajax ответе отправьте его. Например в json, если вам надо несколько параметров в ответе. Или же есть есть базовый url:

    var url = 'http://your.site/page.php';

в success добавляете к нему параметры:

    url = url + '?param1='+res.param1+'&param2='+res.param2;
    document.location.href = url;

Как-то так

Comment: То что нужно, только res. убрал и заработало